# How to force jGroups to bindt to specified interface when have more than one interface

Tags: java, jgroups

I want to run jGroups within a machine with more than one interface. Consider these two interfaces and two IPs:

ens256 -> 172.16.2.2

ens128 -> 192.168.1.2

I want to force my program to bind jGroups channel to ens256 with this command

```
java -jar my.jar -Djgroups.bind_addr=172.16.2.2
```

but in the result I'v got :

```
GMS: address=coordinator, cluster=test, physical address=192.168.1.2:7800
```

I read [this](https://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/docs/Server_Configuration_Guide/4/html/ch19s07s07.html) link and I used [this](https://github.com/belaban/JGroups/blob/master/conf/tcp.xml) as my tcp.xml.
Any hint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems that you're sending the argument to your main method, instead of sending it to the JVM.
To send it as a system property:

```
java -Djgroups.bind_addr=172.16.2.2 -jar my.jar
```

Answer (score 1):

You use an outdated docu, the new one is here: [1]
In [1] (scroll down), you could write the bind address directly into your config, e.g. using `bind_addr="match-address:172.*"`.

[1] http://www.jgroups.org/manual4/index.html#Transport